# keeping form values after POST as a paramter of python file

Tags: php, python, mysql, forms

I have a form, which one submitted goes to a php file and inserts values into DB(MySql).After successfully inserting values into DB,I want to use the values of this parameter form as a python file in another php file when i submitted .

file register.php -> file description.php (button start) -> file exucuter.php( execute  pythonfile)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting to *exucuter.php* after doing your DB insert, if you

```
include 'exucuter.php';  // (assuming they are in the same directory)
```

in *description.php* after the DB does its work, you should be able to use the values directly from `$_POST` in *exucuter.php*. This way you won't have to worry about storing them somewhere or transferring them between the two scripts.

---

If your second script (*description.php*) requires some additional user interaction before your third script (*exucuter.php*) runs, then you can't just include *exucuter.php*, and you do need a way to retain the values from your first script. There are different ways to do this: storing them in the session or in a file or database, putting them in the query string for the form action in *description.php*, or including them as hidden inputs. Here is an example using hidden inputs:

**register.php**

```
<form action="description.php" method="POST">
    <label for="x">X: </label><input type="text" name="x" id="x">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

**description.php**

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['x'])) {  /* Do your DB insert */; } ?>
<form action="exucuter.php" method="POST">

    <!--Use a hidden input to pass the value given in register.php-->
    <input type="hidden" name="x" value="<?php isset($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] : ''; ?>">

    <label for="y">Y: </label><input type="text" name="y" id="y">
    <input type="submit" value="Execute">
</form>
```

**exucuter.php**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['x']) && isset($_POST['y'])) {
    // execute your python program
}
```

Comment: I want to use the values included in register.php and values included in description.php for use as parameters of a python file.
Knowing by clicking on a button found in description.php there will be the execution of python file.

Comment: @sonia I'm sorry I misunderstood at first. I edited the answer.

Comment: can you please tell me about method storing them in session please?